# I want to write all zeros to my hard drive, so I can re-install windows 7

Tags: hard-drive, dd

I am booting from an Ubuntu CD on my laptop. I want to write all zeros to my hard drive, then re-stall Windows 7. I have backed up all the files I want to.

After booting up, I open a terminal window, and type:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1024
```

The computer responds with "permission denied".

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: You would probably need to do this from a live CD, but maybe not.  In either case, you would need to prefix the command with `sudo` so that it looks like `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M`

Comment: hiren's boot cd works great for this...

Answer (score 5):

First off, I'd use the built-in format function in the Disk panel.

However, your mistake is that you're not root. This is very easy to fix. Change your command to:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1024
```

Now, run it. When it asks you for your password, enter it. You will not see characters

---

Generally, whenever you see `Permission Denied`, it means you need to do whatever it is you are trying to do as root. This does NOT mean you should put `sudo` before every command that results in `Permission Denied`. Instead, think of each `Permission Denied` message as this:

> Hey! You! Yes, you. With the pants. This command is going to do something that might be dangerous to your system. Please review it carefully! If you still want to run it, add `sudo` to the beginning of the command.